Relation between linear representation and "induced adjoint representation" of Lie algebra?
Consider a representation $\rho \colon \mathfrak{g} \mapsto \mathrm{End}(V)$ of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ on a vector space $V$. What can we say about the induced representation on the space of matrices $\sigma \colon \mathfrak{g}\mapsto \mathrm{End}(V)$ given by the commutator action $\sigma(X)M = [\rho(X), \ M]$.
This is a sort of "adjoint" representation $\mathrm{ad}_XM$, where we are extending its action to the entire matrix space $\mathrm{End}(V)$, not just the image of the representation $\rho(\mathfrak{g}) \subseteq \mathrm{End}(V)$.
What are properties of $\sigma$ that one can determine purely by looking at $\rho$?
Namely, given the invariant subspaces of $\rho$, what can we say about the invariant subspaces of $\sigma$? Specifically, let us assume that $\frak{g}$ is compact and simple over the real numbers (although I imagine most of the results hold if it is semisimple over any field of characteristic zero).

We just have $\sigma ={\rm ad}\circ \rho$, so the composition of $\rho$ and ${\rm ad}$.

If you are looking at the semisimple case it should be clear to see that $\operatorname{End}(W)$ will be a subrepresentation if $W$ is. Indeed if we split $V$ into irreducible representations $W_i$, we get a block decomposition of $\operatorname{End}(V)$ into pieces of the form $\operatorname{End}(W_i)$ and $\operatorname{Hom}(W_i,W_j)$. Then we will have $\sigma$ embedding $\mathfrak{g}$ into the "block diagonal" part i.e. the $\operatorname{End}(W_i)$. What is going to happen in the off-diagonal parts i.e. the $\operatorname{Hom}(W_i,W_j)$ looks like it might get incredibly complicated to me but I think Schur's Lemma might tell us we have a trivial subrepresentation when $W_i \cong W_j$.
Focusing on just one irreducible representation for simplicity, we should note that we are simply asking for a tensor product decomposition of $V^* \otimes V$. We can see a couple obvious irreducible subrepresentations contained in there. Firstly, a copy of $\mathfrak{g}$ (the image of $\sigma$). There will also be a copy of the trivial representation (the span of the identity). How the rest breaks down will vary. We should notice that $V^* \otimes V$ is self-dual and so the resulting decomposition will have only self-dual reps and pairs of dual reps (I'm not sure if  it will actually have the latter option but I couldn't see immediately how to rule it out).
